# Openlayers 3: Drag -draw bbox with form

Tags: openlayers, jquery

Is it possible to drag/draw a bbox in Openlayers 3 and have the coordinates from this function auto fill-in a form field(s) on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  I can't copy-n-paste from my code, so I retyped it.  Forgive any typos.

html:

```
<form role="form" id="form1" action="submit">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label for="bbox3">Upper Left</label>
            <input type="text" style="font-size: x-small;"
                class="form-control" name="bbox[3]" id="bbox3" placeholder="latitude"/>
            <input type="text" style="font-size: x-small;"
                class="form-control" name="bbox[0]" id="bbox0" placeholder="longitude"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 ">
        <label for="bbox1">Lower Right</label>
            <input type="text" style="font-size: x-small;"
                class="form-control" name="bbox[1]" id="bbox1" placeholder="latitude"/>
            <input type="text" style="font-size: x-small;"
                class="form-control" name="bbox[2]" id="bbox2" placeholder="longitude"/>
    </div>

</form>
```

JS:

```
//Dragbox - select
draw = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
  condition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
    })
  })
});

        /* add the DragBox interaction to the map */
map.addInteraction(draw);

draw.on('boxend', function (evt) {
        var string = draw.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        itest(string);
});

    function itest(myString) {
    var thebox = myString.toString().split(",");
    var long1 = thebox[0];
    var lat1 = thebox[1];
    var long2 = thebox[4];
    var lat2 = thebox[5];
document.getElementById("bbox0").value = long1;
document.getElementById("bbox3").value = lat1;
document.getElementById("bbox2").value = long2;
document.getElementById("bbox1").value = lat2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the [boxend](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.DragBoxEvent.html) event that is emitted when the user finished creating a drag box. Something like

```
dragbox.on('boxend', function(evt) {
  form.coordinates.value = dragbox.getGeometry().getExtent().join(',');
});
```